# How to iterate over a Gurobi decision variable in an integrated normal distribution that includes exponentiation

Tags: python, var, gurobi, numerical-integration

My problem: **Iterating over Gurobi "Var" decision variable** creates **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Var' and 'int'** and **issue with exponentation** (i.e. **/ pow())

Key information on the Gurobi optimization:

- Objective function: for three items maximize the sum of (price * expected value)
- Expected value is calculated through two defined formulas:
- 1) PDF = probability density function
- 2) EV = Expected value which is the integration of the PDF over a
  specific integral
- The decision variable "upperBound" is supposed to maximize the upper bound of this integral, the lower bound is 0

Below the model:

```
from gurobipy import *
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, scipy.integrate as integrate
import math

mu = pd.DataFrame(np.array([10, 15]), index = ["product1", "product2"])
sigma = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1, 1.5]), index = mu.index.values)
price = pd.Series(np.array([10, 10]), index = mu.index.values)

m = Model("maxUpperBound")
ub = m.addVars(mu.index.values, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="upperBound")

def PDF (y, mu, sigma):
    return y * (1.0 / (sigma * (2.0 * math.pi)**(1/2)) * math.exp(-1.0 * (y - mu)**2 / (2.0 * (sigma**2))))

def EV(ub, mu, sigma):
    lb = 0
    value, error = integrate.quad(PDF, lb, ub, args=(mu, sigma))
    return value

m.setObjective(
    quicksum(
        price.loc[i] * EV(ub[i], mu.loc[i], sigma.loc[i])
        for i in mu.index.values
    ),
    GRB.MAXIMIZE)

m.addConstr(
    (quicksum(ub[i]
              for i in mu.index.values)
     <= 100),
    "Limit100"
)

m.optimize()

for v in m.getVars():
    print(v.varName, v.x)
```

Comment: Not providing a minimal, reproducible example dramatically decreases your chances of a getting a helpful answer here. You should put some work in producing a small code block that has the error and can be copy-pasted by everyone.

Comment: How can I make this more reproducible apart from removing the written text between the code lines? Would you also remove the model construct then? @nicoschlömer

Comment: I don't have access to a Gurobi license currently. Can you confirm if the line resulting in the TypeError is this one: `for ub in ub[i]:`?

Comment: @MUCSP_90 That would be something. You can also see if you can use fewer functions/variables. It typically boils down to only one or two. Also, of course you need to make sure to use software that everyone can download. Almost nobody can use Gurobi.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I tried produce a more minimalistic example. It seems to me that Gurobi can be a part of that problem thus I kept that solver. Does this help anyways?

Comment: @dhasson you are correct. I updated the code though to make it more concise and easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gurobi is not able to optimize with respect to the PDF function as this is not a mixed-integer problems comprised of linear, (convex or nonconvex) quadratic, or second-order constraints/objective.

Instead solved this by calculating the expected value upfront for each product_ub combination. ub can takes values between 0 and 100 (see constraint). Used the expected value thereafter in the objective function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit hard to read but these lines likely cause the error:

```
ub = m.addVars(mu.index.values, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="upperBound")
...
for ub in ub[i]:
```

`ub` is a tupledict and `ub[i]` would refer to one Var object. You cannot iterate over a single Var.

I guess you want to write something like this:

```
for ub_i in ub:
```

**EDIT**

The problem has been solved over in the [Gurobi forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360056294732):

tldr: The objective function is too complex and cannot be handled by Gurobi in this form.

Comment: I tried to improve the code and took your suggestion into account. Yet it does not solve the problem